# How to replace words by text box in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a string like:

```
How are __ doing today ?. I'm doing __.
```

I wanted to replace every __ by a text box. So the purpose is '__' is indicated as a fill in the blanks in the question.

Comment: `str.replace(/__/g, '<input type="text" />')`

Comment: Is this really related to angular?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the Angular templates, you can split the string into an array, like so:

```
sentence = "How are __ doing today ?. I'm doing __.";
parts = this.sentence.split("__");
```

Then, in the template, loop through the parts, and add an input for all but the last:

```
<span *ngFor="let part of parts; let last = last">
  {{part}}
  <input type="text" *ngIf="!last"/>  
</span>
```

Here is a StackBlitz to show it working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eau2id?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: you understood my problem exactly. There is little change I'm having string at view not at component side.

Something Like: 
<h4 [innerHTML]="replaceFillBlanks(item.question)"></h4>

Component Part: 
replaceFillBlanks(question){
     this.parts = question.split("__");
     console.log(this.parts);
    }